# Why the S_ISUID and S_ISGID mode bits got cleared when the owner or group of an executable file are changed by an unprivileged user

Tags: permissions, executable, chown, setuid, setgid

I was reading the `man` page of `chown`. I don't understand why `S_ISUID` and `S_ISGID` mode should be cleared when the function returns successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're pointing to this from the man page:

> When  the owner or group of an executable file are changed by an
>   unprivileged user the S_ISUID and S_ISGID mode bits are cleared.

So why are they cleared now. You see they are only cleared in case of an **executable** file.
Because when one of the bits (SUID/SGID) is set, the unprivileged user can execute the file as the new owner of the file. That would be a huge security breach.

Comment: I tested it on my machines (ubuntu 12.04 LTS.)It seems they got cleared no matter whether or not the file is executable. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misread `man 2 chown`: **you** don't have to clear `S_ISUID` and `S_ISGID`, they will automatically be cleared when you use that function as an unprivileged user. If your program is running as `root` the behaviour (on Linux) depends on the kernel version.

If you need the bits set, just reapply them (assuming the account that tries to set them has the privileges to do so).

From the man page:

```
  When  the  owner  or  group  of  an  executable file are changed by an
  unprivileged user the S_ISUID  and  S_ISGID  mode  bits  are  cleared.
  POSIX  does not specify whether this also should happen when root does
  the chown(); the Linux behavior depends on  the  kernel  version.   In
  case  of  a non-group-executable file (i.e., one for which the S_IXGRP
  bit is not set) the S_ISGID bit indicates mandatory  locking,  and  is
  not cleared by a chown().
```